# <h:selectOneRadio> value not updated in bean

Tags: jsf

```
<h:form>
    <h:messages />
        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.selectedValue}" id="selectId"
            layout="pageDirection">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.values}" var="value"
                itemLabel="#{value.text}" itemValue="{value}" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
        <h:commandButton value="Press Me" >
            <f:ajax listener="#{bean.btn_action}" execute="@form"/>
        </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Below are code details.

- Bean is backing bean in @ViewScope.
- bean.values is list of another managed bean which is in @RequestScope.
- Radio button value is binded to above @RequestScope managed bean in backing bean. #{bean.selectedValue}
- selectedValue is reference to object in backing bean having getter/setter.

Issues.
 - When execute=@form is added to ajax tag, listener is not even called.
 - After execute-@form, listener is getting called **however radio button selected value is not updated in backing bean.**
 - When i debug getter is always called for selectedValue never the setter.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `itemValue="{value}"` is just a careless typo and that you never paid attention to the server logs, then this construct will silently fail if `#{value}` represents a non-standard type and you don't have a `Converter` for that type or didn't implement the type's `equals()` method properly.

First step would be adding `render="@form"` to `<f:ajax>`, so that `<h:messages>` get updated as well, so that you don't need to look into server logs for conversion/validation errors.

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{bean.btn_action}" render="@form" />
```

Second step would be fixing the problem based on the shown conversion/validation error. Most likely you've a conversion error *"null converter"* or maybe you already have one, but you're getting a validation error *"value is not valid"* instead.

Both potential problems are answered in detail in the following answers:

- [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-from-a-db/6850681#6850681)
- [Using JSF Converter in h:selectOneMenu results in Validation Error: Value not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605468/using-jsf-converter-in-hselectonemenu-results-in-validation-error-value-not-va/10605832#10605832)